# Getting log from Custom Action with Extra Classes C# in WiX

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action

I am learning at the moment WiX with VS 2015 and I understand it. I found out lots of options (e. g. putting data into the installer, getting info with CAs). But one thing would be also nice to know:
Is it possible to get **logs** not only from Custom Actions but also from some extra classes, which I want to use in the installer? Is there a possible way?

EDIT:
I think some people don't understand my question. That is the reason why I try to do an easy example.
First we have have our custom-action:

```
[Custom Action]
public static ActionResult Example (Session session)
{
   session.Log("Beginn of Custom Action 'Example'");
   NewPath newPath = new NewPath("any path");
   session["NEWPATH"] = newPath.gettingPath();
   session.Log("End of Custom Action 'Example'");
   return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

And to get the path in this example I need an extra class in C#:

```
namespace Path
{
   private string _path;
   class NewPath
   {
      public NewPath(string path)
      {
         this._path = path;
      }
      public string gettingPath()
      {
         if(Directory.exists(this._path))
         {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(this._path);
         }
         return this._path;
      }
   }
}
```

And now I wanna try to get also **logs** from the class `gettingPath`
I hope this example is understandable (and there are no mistakes :D)

EDIT 2: Added some things to end my class. And **THIS** is only a little example. Of course it's not absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

gettingPath() is a member method of the class NewPath.
The only interface I know to the wix logging session from a custom action is the `Session` object.

You can pass the session object to a class within a custom action, for example NewPath.

Another option is to define a static NLog in the class containing the custom actions signatures.

```
_logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

and configure NLog target as the same session object. That way you can use _logger anywhere in the containing class.

For more information about NLog, see http://nlog-project.org/

Comment: Nice answer. But I want use it without any other projects. Is it still possible?

Answer (score 0):

In general it seems that you're going about this the wrong way. Custom actions are the LAST thing you should learn, and that's after finding out what Windows Installer can do without any code at all. WiX and Windows Installer are not some coding framework for all your classes. It's a data-driven install where custom actions should be avoided if at all possible. The WiX inventor/owner says that custom actions are an admission of failure:

http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/8/17/zataoca-custom-actions-are-generally-an-admission-of-failure/

So instead of talking about classes and coding, whatever you want to do might already be available with WiX built-in custom actions, Windows Installer capabilities, or WiX Util functions. In your case, it appears from your code that you might be trying to get a path to use. Rather than describe your coding issue you should say what it is you are trying to accomplish with that code because there might be any number of ways to solve the problem that do not require any code at all.

Your code also contains a CreateDirectory call, which is not recommended at all because 1) Windows Installer/WiX can do that without code and 2) everything you do (such as create a directory) in your custom action requires a rollback custom action to delete it if the install fails and an uninstall custom action (or equivalent) to delete it. This is part of why code should be avoided if at all possible.

I assume you have worked through the WiX tutorial:

https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/

and maybe the book WiX: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML, as well as all the examples available.

Logging is a built-in Windows Installer capability - the log is produced with a msiexec command line that includes /l*vx, and your log entries will be included there. In managed code custom actions it's the session object that provides logging. So this might only be a C# programming question because you want to access the session object (to do logging) from other places in your code. In that case and with your example code, your NewPath constructor just needs an overload that takes the Session object and keeps a local reference in the class. Or you have an overload to the gettingPath method that takes a Session as a parameter.

In the Win32 world MsiProcessMessage and C++ custom actions are what you would use.

Comment: Nice answer, but it doesn't help me, becaus this answer doesn't replies my question. I know that I don't need creating a new directory. WiX can do it itself. But my code, which I don't want to show, has something more than this example.

Comment: "So this might only be a C# programming question because you want to access the session object (to do logging) from other places in your code. In that case and with your example code, your NewPath constructor just needs an overload that takes the Session object and keeps a local reference in the class. Or you have an overload to the gettingPath method that takes a Session as a parameter. " - An how is that possilble? That is my question.